# magento 1.9 chinese language pack not found

Tags: magento-1.9, language-package

I searched for magento 1 chenese language but not found any extension.

Can you please suggest me if any link for this package.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below link:

and download repected language pack:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140717210430/http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations/

Thanks